# Tab page and Group box control in SSRS 2005

Tags: reportingservices-2005

Is there any way to show multiple report pages in single report viewer? If yes the how? Please tell me step by step or any direct link?

Is TAB Page control and Group box control are available in SSRS 2005 or it may available to download these control from any website?

Actually I have more than 5 different reports and have to show each report in a single tab page(Is it possible or any other idea, please)

and secondly I  have to group some controls/data in group then after I can hide/unhide group box in place of all controls/data.

Please help on both problems...

Thanks in advance:
Shashi

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this INSIDE a report is to add 5 sub reports to the main report with a page break after. Then, Add a DocumentMapLabel for each report. You will be able to navigate to each sub report using the document map. ---Another option is to make an ASP.NET (or just html) page with links to each.